# Not extrapolating between values in ListPlot3D

Tags: plotting

I am plotting points using ListPlot3D. I have "Null" points in my list that I do not want to be plotted but the program decides to extrapolate over those null points by using the next closest values. How can I get the plot to not extrapolate between the points surrounding my "Null" point and simply have my plot cut off at the points next to my Null points?

Comment: Example from the docs: `ListPlot3D[
 ReplacePart[
  Partition[Range[100], 
   10], {{3, 3} -> None, {5, 7} -> I, {8, 4} -> 
    Missing["NotAvailable"]}], Mesh -> All]`

Comment: Plotting the example you provided, the mesh only has one diagonal line through each cell. This leads to the empty regions having an elongated diamond shape rather than a square (rotated 45$^\circ$ w.r.t the grid). Is there anyway to make my grid finer so that I don't have to exclude such large chunks of my space?

Comment: `ListPlot3D` triangulates a tensor grid, which means triangles get deleted from the output as you saw in the example.  You could use the FEM `ElementMesh` functions to construct a `QuadElement` mesh.  An easier way does not occur to me right now.